# How to fix this with Retrfit 2.0

Tags: java, android, retrofit2

How to fix it?

```
Process: www.palchiki.com.palchiki, PID: 2047
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unable to create converter for class www.palchiki.com.palchiki.model.ServiceResponse
for method APIWebService.getServices
at retrofit2.Utils.methodError(Utils.java:154)
at retrofit2.MethodHandler.createResponseConverter(MethodHandler.java:62)
at retrofit2.MethodHandler.create(MethodHandler.java:33)
at retrofit2.Retrofit.loadMethodHandler(Retrofit.java:164)
at retrofit2.Retrofit$1.invoke(Retrofit.java:145)
at java.lang.reflect.Proxy.invoke(Proxy.java:393)
at $Proxy2.getServices(Unknown Source)
at www.palchiki.com.palchiki.fragment.ServiceFragment.onCreateView(ServiceFragment.java:94)
at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1962)
```

I use com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.0.0-beta3 and com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.0.0-beta3

Comment: Paste the error text, not a screenshot of it!

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem and adding addCallAdapterFactory to retrofit saved me.

```
Retrofit.Builder().baseUrl(BASE_URL)
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson))
                .addCallAdapterFactory(RxJava3CallAdapterFactory.create())
                .client(provideOkHttpClient())
                .build();
```

for using RxJava3CallAdapterFactory you should adding

```
 implementation "io.reactivex.rxjava3:rxjava:$rxVersion"
```

in dependencies.

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit:retrofit:2.0.0-beta2'
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit:converter-gson:2.0.0-beta2'
```